# Always encrypted: Importing certificates to certificate store "My" in location "Current user"

Tags: import, certificate, store

I'm trying to make EF6 work with always encrypted, but I'm having troubles introducing the certificates made by `SQL Management Tool` to the store location "Current user". 
This is the error I get when I query the encrypted data:

> Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: '21-14-01-0E-87-A1-04-97-CE-5F'.

> Certificate with thumbprint 'C*******************************9839' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.

```
Parameter name: masterKeyPath
```

I tried adding necessary certificates via `mmc.exe` to the Current user's personal store, but still when I run this:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(certificate.Thumbprint.ToString());
}
```

...the store is empty. I'm out of ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: SQL server runs under different user than you. I would place the certificate (with private key - pkcs12) in LocalMachine\My store and assign rights to the private key for user that SQL server runs under.

Comment: The second part, assigning rights to the private key, how would I do that?

Comment: Open MMC => Add Certificates (Local computer) snap-in => Certificates (Local Computer) => Personal => Certificates => Right click the certificate of interest => All tasks => Manage private key

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the situation is still the same.